# Playframework always operation timeout on about 16k-th request from ApacheBench if keep-alive flag not set

Tags: http, playframework

An activator template project was created by

```
activator new rest-benchmark simple-rest-scala
cd rest-benchmark
activator clean stage
target/universal/stage/bin/rest-benchmark -Dplay.crypto.secret=1234
```

the template can be found [here](https://github.com/amitdev/simple-rest-scala)

Then I run `ApacheBench` to get a rough idea of playframework's throughput:

`ab -n 20000 -c 5 http://127.0.0.1:9000/books`

which always give similar result - timeout at around 16.3k-th request:

```
apr_socket_recv: Operation timed out (60)
Total of 16345 requests completed
```

However, if I run `ab` with `-k KeepAlive`:

`ab -k -n 20000 -c 5 http://127.0.0.1:9000/books`

The benchmark was able to complete.

I have several questions:

1. Why always timeout when `Keep Alive` is absent? Shouldn't play be able to handle requests regardless of this header? Or is it my OS keep the connection open, hence no further requests can be processed?
2. Why around the 16300-th request? Is it related to ulimit?
3. If missing `Keep Alive` will cause connection timeout, what can I do in production?

**Edit:** Switched to play 2.5.4

**Edit2:** Changed app launch command as marcospereira suggested, observing same result

Comment: Which version of Play? There were some recent fixes related to keep alive connections. Try with version 2.5.4. Also, running with `activator run` is not the proper way to test performance/throughput. See the [docs for more information](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying#Running-a-production-server-in-place).

Comment: I'm using 2.3.10, will update my findings after switching. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @marcospereira Switched to play 2.5.4, same result

Comment: Yes. Because you are still using "run" which is not supposed to be used that way. Remember, "run"  is a slower mode that does code reload, recompiles code, etc.

Comment: @marcospereira Thank you for your recommendation. I have changed accordingly

Comment: Please, share the results later.